How to bypass Lambda Authorizer in API Gateway
I have a (public) API Gateway that uses a custom Lambda authorizer that we need to both (a) authorize custom access token and (b) JWTs.
We now want to trigger another Lambda (via EventBridge Scheduler) to send a request to our backend via the API Gateway, but we're having problems on deciding how to authorize or bypass those calls.
From our discussions we came up with following solutions:

Set up a mirror API Gateway inside our VPC with no authorization and call that from the Lambda

Roll our own "auth" via a rotating token that we store in the Secret Manager


Before going forward with one of those solutions, I want to make sure that we're not missing something very easy and obvious to either bypass the custom authorization Lambda calls or authorize them (e.g. signing via aws-sig4?)

Why don't you just call the Lambda directly from the second Lambda?

SAE's suggestion, I think, is direct invocation of the 2nd Lambda function using an AWS SDK, relying on the 1st Lambda function's execution role for auth. You could also do this via a signed function URL call if you prefer not to use the AWS SDK.
